# Git: How can I merge local branch into remote master branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

I am using git to control my code version. I firstly clone the repository from Github using command:

> git clone my_website -b master

And then in my local computer I create my "dep-k" branch:

> git branch dep-k

So I began to develop my project in "dep-k" branch. However, during development, I create a lot of new files and directories, I found they can't be merged into master branch. Only the file that exists originally in master can be updated by dep-k when I merge branch dep-k into master branch. So how can I also merge my new created file and directory into master either? Thanks

Comment: Maybe with a pull request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the person who put this question. I found my master branch version is not compatible with Github. So I pull it first and merge them, and then push it again. Also I used

> git push -f

this command to force pushing(this command will overwrite all file of repository in my Github server). Anyway, thank all for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're collaborating on a GitHub project that somebody else owns, you commit your changes and push them to remote branch, then you submit a pull request so that the owner can review and approve your changes.

If the repo is yours, just do:

```
git branch master
git merge --squash dep-k
git commit "some commit message"
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the new files to staging? When you commit, make sure you're doing both of the two stages, 'add' and 'commit'.  You can check if they're staged properly during the process with `git status` and `git diff`.

For example, the new files could be added to staging individually, `git add <filename>`, or in a larger group, `git add -A`.

Then, use `git commit -m "Enter commit message here"` to commit the snapshot to history.

[Helpful cheatsheet of the workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Egze.png).

[More info on `git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add).

Also, since those files may not have been staged or committed as you thought they were, be careful when trying to revise any history before this point.

Once they're merged locally, then you'd use `git push` to get the changes to appear remotely. Make sure you have the upstreams all set properly for the branches.